# How make item Visible/Invisible in Main Layout OnDismiss Dialog Fragment event?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, dialogfragment

I have created dialog fragment in my Xamrin Android application. 
On button click from main layout, i am opening dialouge fragment.On dialouge fragment activity creation I am hiding(invisible) all buttons on home page(working perfectly in my application). 
On fragment dismiss event I need to make all items on main layout visible.I am getting error while using OnDismiss() event.

Masinactivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Views;

namespace MyHome
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyHome", MainLauncher = true,Icon ="@drawable/Icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Button mbtnGoToRoom;
        private Button mbtnGoToSettings;
        private Button mBtnOverview;
        private ToggleButton mBtnStatus;
        private ProgressBar mprogressBar;

        protected override void OnRestart()
        {
            base.OnRestart();

            mbtnGoToRoom.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnOverview.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mbtnGoToSettings.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mprogressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            var mClock = FindViewById<DigitalClock>(Resource.Id.digitalClock1);
            mClock.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

           mbtnGoToRoom = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnGoToRoom);
           mBtnOverview = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnOverview);
           mbtnGoToSettings = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnSetting);
           mBtnStatus = FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.BtnStatus);
           mprogressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
            var mClock = FindViewById<DigitalClock>(Resource.Id.digitalClock1);

            mbtnGoToRoom.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                mbtnGoToRoom.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                mBtnOverview.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                mbtnGoToSettings.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                mBtnStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                mprogressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                mClock.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;


                //Pull up Room menu
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                Rooms room = new Rooms();
                room.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
            };

            mbtnGoToSettings = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnSetting);

            mbtnGoToSettings.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {

                //Pull up Room menu
                FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                Settings settings = new Settings();
                settings.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
            };
        }    
    }
}
```

Rooms.cs (Dialog Fragment Activity)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using static Android.Provider.CalendarContract;

namespace MyHome
{

    class Rooms : DialogFragment


    {
        Android.Media.MediaPlayer player;
        private Button mBtnGoToHall;
        private Button mBtnGoToBroom1;
        private Button mBtnGoToBroom2;
        private Button mBtnGoToKitchen;
        private Button mBtnGoToBalcony;
        private Button mBtnGoToGarden;


        private Button mbtnGoToRoom;
        private Button mbtnGoToSettings;
        private Button mBtnOverview;
        private ToggleButton mBtnStatus;
        private ProgressBar mprogressBar;



        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Room_Menu, container, false);


            mBtnGoToHall = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnHall);
            mBtnGoToHall.Click += mBtnGoToHall_Click;

            mBtnGoToBroom1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBedroom1);
            mBtnGoToBroom1.Click += mBtnGoToBroom1_Click;

            mBtnGoToBroom2 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBedroom2);
            mBtnGoToBroom2.Click += mBtnGoToBroom2_Click;

            mBtnGoToKitchen = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnKitchen);
            mBtnGoToKitchen.Click += mBtnGoToKitchen_Click;

            mBtnGoToBalcony = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBalcony);
            mBtnGoToBalcony.Click += mBtnGoToBalcony_Click;

            mBtnGoToGarden = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGarden);
            mBtnGoToGarden.Click += mBtnGoToGarden_Click;




            return view;
        }

        private void mBtnGoToHall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtHall));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void mBtnGoToBroom1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtBedroom1));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void mBtnGoToBroom2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtBedroom2));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void mBtnGoToKitchen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtKitchen));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void mBtnGoToBalcony_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtBalcony));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }

        private void mBtnGoToGarden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            player.Start();
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(ActvtGarden));
            StartActivity(intent);
            this.Dismiss();
        }



        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {


            player = Android.Media.MediaPlayer.Create(Context, Resource.Raw.Door);
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation; //set the animation
            Dialog.Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));


        }
        public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnDismiss(dialog);
            mbtnGoToRoom = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnGoToRoom);
            mBtnOverview = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnOverview);
            mbtnGoToSettings = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnSetting);
            mBtnStatus = View.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.BtnStatus);
            mprogressBar = View.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
            var mClock = View.FindViewById<DigitalClock>(Resource.Id.digitalClock1);

            mbtnGoToRoom.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnOverview.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mbtnGoToSettings.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mprogressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mClock.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keuOf.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKhC5.jpg)

Comment: I have a couple of questions first tell me where do the buttons and everything else whose visibility you are trying to change are? Are they on the dialogFragment axml or the Activity axml secondly are you using the appcompat library or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you can't get your buttons in `OnDismiss()`. I think you should pass them into the rooms class when you create it.
For example, in MainActivity:

```
             FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
             Rooms room = new Rooms(mbtnGoToRoom, mbtnGoToSettings, mBtnOverview, mBtnStatus, mprogressBar, mClock);                  
             room.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
```

In Rooms.cs:

```
        private Button mbtnGoToRoom;
        private Button mbtnGoToSettings;
        private Button mBtnOverview;
        private ToggleButton mBtnStatus;
        private ProgressBar mprogressBar;
        private DigitalClock mClock;

        public Rooms(Button mbtnGoToRoom, Button mbtnGoToSettings,Button mBtnOverview,ToggleButton mBtnStatus, ProgressBar mprogressBar, DigitalClock mClock)
        {
            this.mbtnGoToRoom = mbtnGoToRoom;
            this.mBtnOverview = mbtnGoToSettings;
            this.mbtnGoToSettings = mBtnOverview;
            this.mBtnStatus = mBtnStatus;
            this.mprogressBar = mprogressBar;
            this.mClock = mClock;
        }
        public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnDismiss(dialog);
            mbtnGoToRoom.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnOverview.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mbtnGoToSettings.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mBtnStatus.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mprogressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mClock.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you...It's Working